# Imaginary part of An Squre Root Integration

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am looking for a particular form of an integral which some simplified version of it has the following form
$$
\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+u^4-u^6}}{u^5}du.
$$
Could someone gives some idea for that? It is better to learn me fishing because I may use it in different cases.

Comment: @OlivierOloa did you read the question properly? near 0 the integral might not be convergent but the imaginary part has to be zero, since $1+u^4-u^6<0$ only for $|u|>t$ where t is approximately 1.2!!

Comment: For its real part you are right. But I am looking for its imaginary part which is not divergent.

Comment: Maybe you could write $\Im \int$ instead.

Comment: $\int\Im{}$ would be better.

Comment: @  Julián Yes. Maybe it is better to write it in that form.